# How to read a PHP JSON return in Java

Tags: java, android, json

I have a Java(actually Android eventually) program in which I want to call a php script hosted on a server(not localhost to me) and in the script it returns some JSON information, and I was wondering, through Java, what is the best way to get the JSON data, and then how to make that a string or byte array? I know this is a lot so if you can only help with a small piece it all helps, also if you have a link or website I should look at I would love to see them. Thank you very much for all of your help.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with PHP... but you want a json parser for Java such as: https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/

Comment: Thank you, as I said any part helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this very helpful.
 http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/08/develop-android-login-registration-with-php-mysql.html/4

And also this:
http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

I made a simple app that gets a trivia question from a web mySQL database. The PHP stored on the server accepts a POST argument and then just uses "echo" to return a string, which I then parse in my Java code to retrieve the needed information. That was the most basic way I could think of to do it.

```
<?php
//connect to database
include 'connect.php';
 //get the question number from POST encrypted argument
$num = $_POST['NUM'];
//Query the Database with the NUM argument to retrieve question
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT QUESTION, A, B, C, D, ANSWER FROM trivia where num=        '$num' ");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$i = '0';
$question = $row[0];
$A = $row[1];
$B = $row[2];
$C = $row[3];
$D = $row[4];
$answer = $row[5];

//returns question, multichice answers, and answer seperated by '#' and '*'
if($question){
echo "$question#$A#$B#$C#$D*$answer";
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I then parse that string in Java with a bunch of if/else statements that look for the separating characters. As I said, very basic, but it works.

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to do something very similar so this was very helpful.